# next.js application nginx not loading css and js. Runs perfectly when specify port (3000)

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

i have deployed a nextjs app on AWS ec2 instance running ubuntu and nginx

using pm2 to run nextjs

the proxy pass entry in nginx conf is like

```
location / {
        # reverse proxy for next server
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        # we need to remove this 404 handling
        # because next's _next folder and own handling
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

My problem is that when I specify port in the ip like http://10.20.30.40:3000 my site comes up properly with all css and javascript loaded

but when no port is specified like http://10.20.30.40 my css and javascript are not loaded and I can see only text

What is wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to serve the static assets from the Nginx.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Add the below code in your server config file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
location /_next/static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/PROJECT_FOLDER/.next/static;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
}
```

Full reference: https://gist.github.com/iam-hussain/2ecdb934a7362e979e3aa5a92b181153

Answer (score 0):

For my case I am using Ubuntu server and I put my nextjs project under **/var/www/marketplace-web-app** directory. So my nginx script I wrote like this

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <SERVER_IP OR DOMAIN_NAME>;

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_min_length 256;

        location /_next/static {
                alias /var/www/marketplace-web-app/.next/static;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
        }


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; #change to 3001 for second app, but make sure second nextjs app starts on new port in packages.json "star>                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Hope this help and let's me know in the comment. Happy coding!